# jquery class selector doesn't work in IE6

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-6

Eidt: Thanks to all and sorry for my carelessness. The `initTree()` fails.

This works fine in FF and Chrome:

```
$("#tree").treeview({
    collapse:false,
});
```

This works fine in FF Chrome and IE6:

```
$("#tree").treeview({
    collapse:false  //<-here is the key, no comma
});
```

I have a tree like:

```
<ul id="tree">
    <li>Root
        <ul>
            <li>Node_1_2<a class='addnode'>add</a><a class='deletenode'>delete</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Node_2_4<a class='addnode'>add</a><a class='deletenode'>delete</a></li>
                    <li>Node_2_6</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I click the `<a>add</a>`, it should append a chid node to that element. Something like:

```
$("a.addnode").live("click", function() {
    if($(this).parent().children("ul").html() == null){
        leafHtml = ...;
        $(this).parent().append(leafHtml);
    }
    else{
        leafHtml = ...;
        $(this).parent().children("ul").append(leafHtml);
    }
    initTree();
});
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome. But in IE6 it did nothing. Seem like `$("a.addnode")` didn't work.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU USING IE6??? ANYONE WHO TELLS YOU THEY 'HAVE TO' USE IE6 NEEDS TO BE CONVINCED OTHERWISE.  PLEASE!

Comment: HeyHey, I agree with you. But you know, the clients are always right.

Comment: Ars Technica has some stats saying that IE6 is still around 10% of the market share: http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/07/internet-explorer-gains-market-share-so-does-ie6.ars

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? If it's an older version, have you tried replacing it with a newer one?

Comment: I am in the same industry and a bit of free advice.  At a stage of the project, much earlier than coding you say, "What browsers are you targeting, so that we can build our test plan?"  When they say IE6, you strongly advise against that and if they still adamantly disagree they do not trust you as a business partner and you say, "Have a nice day! Please find a new partner"... you may be stuck now, but there are bigger fish to fry.  move on.

Comment: In China it's 70% because of the WindowsXP without licenses.

Comment: good call, refining that search to the united states it seems to be more like 2-3%... http://getclicky.com/marketshare/us/web-browsers/#/marketshare/us/web-browsers/internet-explorer/  ... although I just looked at some google analytics for a few sites I built and manage, and there are IE6 views within the last month, not many, about 5%

Comment: Our company had a Internet based assessment system and is now developing on something similar to SNS. I just went to check my visits statistics. Around 70% used IE, and 50% of that were IE6. So 35% still sticked to IE6. But can anyone please help with my question or you all suggest to advise clients out of IE6.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need some way to debug what is happening. There are things like Firebug lite you can check out but I would suggest just placing a couple of alerts.

```
$("a.addnode").live("click", function() {
    alert('click caught');
    if($(this).parent().children("ul").html() == null){
        alert('no children');
        leafHtml = ...;
        $(this).parent().append(leafHtml);
    }
    else{
        alert('children');
        leafHtml = ...;
        $(this).parent().children("ul").append(leafHtml);
    }
    alert('end');
    initTree();
});
```

You will know what get's called and what doesn't get called instead of guessing. If I should take a guess there are two errors here that cause this problem. Your selector is fine.

1:  $(this).parent().children("ul").html() == null will never be true. You should check against $(this).parent().children("ul").children().length == 0 instead.

2:  $(this).parent().children("ul").append(leafHtml) makes no sense. Text inside an ul is not valid and I wouldn't be suprised if IE6 just ignores it(it should).

I suspect that #1 makes #2 always happend and as that is invalid IE6 just ignores it.

Comment: Ohh and don't forget to remove the alerts when you are ready.

Comment: Thanks for the debug advice. It turns out to be that `initTree()` fails. I edited the original post to explain why.

Comment: Good that you found it but the other things will still produce invalid html so I would fix that too. It will help you when you have to maintain the code later.

Comment: I've fixed your `#1`. But `#2` works fine, so I'll wait and pay attention to the results.